# Recieving Camera Error 100 taking several photos on Nexus S

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when I try to take several pictures from the front facing camera in a sequence and I have no clue why.`05-24 10:20:25.777: ERROR/Camera(4456): Error 100`

I'm taking the next next photo always in the last PictureCallback:

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback());
```

And in my jpegCallback I'm calling takePicture() again using a global variable as a counter. 
As I was debugging through my code I saw that the error occurs right after calling camera.takePicture(..) for the first time. Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called startPreview() after you have made a shot (before second shot)?